# Matrices addition program explanation

Tags: c

The following program adds two matrices together:

```
for(i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
  for(j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
  }
}
```

I have used and tested this program and it works perfectly fine. I'm just having a hard time understanding how it really works.

I know the addition is being stored in a separate multidimensional array and it seems to be a nested loop way of adding the matrices. But how are the loops adding the numbers?

Comment: What do you mean? The addition happens right here: `c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];`

Answer (score 0):

There are tree 2D arrays with size, loop performs operation for each value stored in the array c using values from array a and b. As loop executes i and j changes ranging from 0 to m and 0 to n so loop may assign sum of `a[0][0]` and `b[0][0]` to `c[0][0]` or even `a[10][2]` and `b[10][2]` to `c[10][2]`, there is nothing complex about it, same combination of numbers logically refers to same location of memory relative to first element of given array as position is calsulated like `first_element_position + idx * element_size`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just having a hard time understanding how it really works.

Well let's suppose the matrix `a` is like this `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` and `b` is `{{6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}` so the loop iterates over both in this case `2` times, so `i` will hold `0` in the first time and then loop over the inner array so in this case `3` times so the first looping process is like writing

```c
c[0][0] = a[0][0] + b[0][0];
// c[0][0] = 1 + 6
```

Then the second iteration

```c
c[0][1] = a[0][1] + b[0][1];
// c[0][1] = 2 + 5
```

and so on

**Code example:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **sumMatrix(int, int in_len, int [][in_len], int [][in_len]);
void printMatrix(int, int in_len, int [][in_len]);
void printAllocatedMatrix(int **m, int, int);
void freeAllocatedMatrix(int **, int);

// since we use these two numbers a lot let's just define them as constants
#define M 2
#define N 3

int main() {
  int a[][N] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, b[][N] = {{6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}};
  // declare and initialise the `c` variable(pointer of a pointer) an allocated matrix that is the sum of both `a` and `b`
  int **c = sumMatrix(M, N, a, b);
  printf("==========\nMatrix A:\n==========\n");
  printMatrix(M, N, a);
  printf("\n==========\nMatrix B:\n==========\n");
  printMatrix(M, N, b);
  // print the allocated matrix `c`
  printf("\n==========\nMatrix C:\n==========\n");
  printAllocatedMatrix(c, M, N);
  // free the allocated memory for the matrix `c`
  freeAllocatedMatrix(c, M);
  return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief  Sum two matrices
///
/// \param len     The number of arrays in the matrix
/// \param in_len  The number of integers in each array
/// \param m_a     The first matrix
/// \param m_b     The second matrix
///
/// \return  A new matrix (The sum of both given matrices)
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int **sumMatrix(int len, int in_len, int m_a[][in_len], int m_b[][in_len]) {
  // allocate memory for the first dimension of the matrix
  int **m = malloc(sizeof(int *) * len);
  for(int i = 0;i < len; i++) {
    // allocate memory for the second dimension
    m[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * in_len);
    // just add the current integer from both given matrices
    for(int j = 0;j < in_len; j++) {
      m[i][j] = m_a[i][j] + m_b[i][j];
    }
  }
  // return the address of the matrix pointer
  return m;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief  Print the allocated matrix in a well format
///
/// \param m       The allocated matrix to print
/// \param len     The number of arrays in the matrix
/// \param in_len  The number of integers in each array
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void printAllocatedMatrix(int **m, int len, int in_len) {
  // just some formatting to show a good output
  printf("{\n");
  for(int i = 0;i < len; i++) {
    printf("  {");
    for(int j = 0;j < in_len; j++) {
      // just print the integer with a comma(`,`) only if it's not the last otherwise just the int
      printf("%d%s", m[i][j], j != in_len - 1 ? ", " : "");
    }
    // the same goes here
    printf("}%s\n", i != len - 1 ? "," : "");
  }
  printf("}");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief  Print the matrix in a well format
///
/// \param m       The matrix to print
/// \param len     The number of arrays in the matrix
/// \param in_len  The number of integers in each array
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void printMatrix(int len, int in_len, int m[][in_len]) {
  // just some formatting to show a good output
  printf("{\n");
  for(int i = 0;i < len; i++) {
    printf("  {");
    for(int j = 0;j < in_len; j++) {
      // just print the integer with a comma(`,`) only if it's not the last otherwise just the int
      printf("%d%s", m[i][j], j != in_len - 1 ? ", " : "");
    }
    // the same goes here
    printf("}%s\n", i != len - 1 ? "," : "");
  }
  printf("}");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief  Free the allocated memory for the matrix
///
/// \param m    The allocated matrix to free
/// \param len  The number of allocated arrays in the allocated matrix
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void freeAllocatedMatrix(int **m, int len) {
  for(int i = 0;i < len; i++) {
    free(m[i]);
  }
  free(m);
}
```

**Output**

```
==========
Matrix A:
==========
{
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 6}
}
==========
Matrix B:
==========
{
  {6, 5, 4},
  {3, 2, 1}
}
==========
Matrix C:
==========
{
  {7, 7, 7},
  {7, 7, 7}
}
```

Note that the code is dynamic so you can add other matrices of different sizes as well for example `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}}` and `{{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {50, 40, 30, 20, 10}, {500, 400, 300, 200, 100}}` so you need to change only three lines

```
#define M 3
#define N 5
```

and

```
int a[][N] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}},
  b[][N] = {{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {50, 40, 30, 20, 10}, {500, 400, 300, 200, 100}};
```

**and the output is:**

```
==========
Matrix A:
==========
{
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
  {10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
  {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}
}
==========
Matrix B:
==========
{
  {5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
  {50, 40, 30, 20, 10},
  {500, 400, 300, 200, 100}
}
==========
Matrix C:
==========
{
  {6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
  {60, 60, 60, 60, 60},
  {600, 600, 600, 600, 600}
}
```

You may noticed the sum always is the same, I meant to do so to make it clear that the output is correct without the need to check manually :D